# Why reference variable needs to initialise while declaring

Tags: c++

It is pretty  simple question i had a doubt and i thought to ask everyone,

as we know we can declare reference as

```
int bar;
int &foo = bar;
```

My question is what is the reason behind this initialisation? Why this is must?
Also Why i don't need to initialise pointers while declaration?

```
int bar;
int *p;
p = &bar;
```

Comment: @John3136 c++ pointer variables

Comment: Perhaps the simplest explanation is that if you have an existing `int &foo;` variable declared and you say `foo = 5;` then this assigns the value 5 to the referent. So if you say `foo = some_other_int;`, how can the language tell the difference between "assign the value stored in `some_other_int` to the int referred to by `foo`" and "rebind `foo` to refer to `some_other_int`?" Because assignment to a reference means "set the value of the referent object," there is no syntax aside from initialization to bind a reference. Therefore, it must be done at initialization time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A reference, by definition, must *refer* to a valid object or POD type. It's not allowed to be uninitialized, referring to nothing in particular. Also, once initialized it can't be changed to refer to something else. Thus the only place it makes sense to initialize it is in the declaration (or if it's a member variable, the initializer list of the class constructor).

Other languages allow null references and reassigning references, but that's not the way they work in C++.

Answer (score 5):

While pointers can be NULL (i.e., point to nothing), a reference must always point to something; it has no NULL state. Thus, it can't be created without being initialized.

Comment: Why reference variables can not be NULL, if pointers can? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Dipak references and pointers are different  , there's no reason to expect that a reference shares any particular property of a pointer. If they were the same then there would be no need for both...

Comment: References must refer to an object (as opposed to no object) because the C++ standard mandates that it be so.